# Javascript Slider event handles

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

I am new to this site and I would like to know more how to handle events in slider with jquery-mobile. I've tried basic events like bind,slidestop, etc.. but nothing happens. I just want to get a prompt message when the slider value changes. Bellow is my code for JS and HTML.

JS:

```
$('#mstrbedroom').on({ 
  start: function(event,ui){ 
    alert("halaka");
  },
  stop: function(event,ui){ 
    alert("agoy");
  }
});
```

HTML CODE:

```
<label for="mstrbedroom">Dimmer</label>
<input name="mstrbedroom" id="mstrbedroom" min="0" max="100" value="50" type="range">
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not binding any events.  The on function requires the `event` parameter which is the first parameter, in this case I believe you want `slide`.  Please read through: http://api.jquery.com/on/.

Try the following and please go through (pretty much the whole page or at least the events section) http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#event-slide:

```
$('#mstrbedroom').slider({
    start: function(event,ui) {
        alert("halaka");
    },
    stop: function(event,ui) {
        alert("agoy");
    }
});
```